# WebView (react-native-webview) getting error code -1 in Expo SDK36

Tags: javascript, react-native, expo, react-native-webview

My Expo App's WebViewScreen Code:

```
import React from 'react';
import { WebView } from 'react-native-webview';

export default WebViewScreen = () => (
    <WebView
        originWhitelist={['*']}
        source={{ uri: 'https://www.google.com' }}
    />
);
```

but when i run it, i get following error:

```
Encountered an error loading page, Object {
  "canGoBack": false,
  "canGoForward": false,
  "code": -1,
  "description": "net::ERR_CACHE_MISS",
  "loading": false,
  "target": 3,
  "title": "Web page not available",
  "url": "https://www.google.com/",
}
```

**NOTE:**
My Android phone is connected to wifi, and I am able to consume backend-server APIs almost on every screen in my Expo app, which confirms that **internet is reachable and my app has the permission to use internet**.

**My Environment:**
Android Samsung phone (Android version 5.1.1),
EXPO SDK version is 36,
[react-native-webview](https://github.com/react-native-community/react-native-webview) version 8.0.6,
[Expo client app](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=host.exp.exponent&hl=en) version 2.14.0

**PS:**
For [react-native-webview](https://github.com/react-native-community/react-native-webview),
**I did NOT do `npm install --save react-native-webview`**,
**instead, i did `expo install react-native-webview`** with **expo-cli** version 3.11.7

**PPS:** I tried running the expo snack of webview from [here](https://snack.expo.io/@wodin/webview-example) (official?) on my phone via QR code scan, yet got the **same error (`"code": -1`)**.

Can someone guide how to get rid of this error and get the webview up and running?

Answer (score 0):

Did you set the right permission in your manifest?

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
```

In your case it should be the App.json file

Comment: In Expo Apps, `app.json` does not contain any ```<uses-permission ... >``` tag, I have read official docs about Expo's app.json [here](https://docs.expo.io/versions/latest/workflow/configuration). Interestingly I found there that **"To use ALL permissions supported by Expo, do not specify the "permissions" key."**, which i have not. For some permissions I am explicitly asking user for Camera/Location permissions during runtime. **Also please note** that I am able to consume backend-server APIs almost on every screen in my Expo app, which confirms that my app has the permission to use internet.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try the temporary fix posted [here](https://github.com/react-native-community/react-native-webview/issues/671#issuecomment-505456457)?

They say that there could be a problem with the websites service workers (due to a [bug](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=977784) in Chrome 75).

The solution involves injecting this JS script to the `WebView`, to unregister the stalled service workers:

```js
navigator.serviceWorker.getRegistrations().then(function(registrations) {
    for (let registration of registrations) {
        registration.unregister();
    }
});
```